# What is the best practice of java string template? Is Apache Commons StrSubstitutor the right tool to choose?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I think StrSubstitutor's usage as a string template is quite clean in Java.
But it is deprecated, can I still use it for a long time?

Comment: Please read this: http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/27.  Also, the answer to "id it the right tool" is "it depends".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadocs say:

> "Deprecated as of 1.3, **use [`StringSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) instead**. This class will be removed in 2.0."

Reference: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StrSubstitutor.html ... and follow the chain.

> can I still use it for a long time?

You can use it until version 2.0 of the API is released<sup>1</sup>.  We can't predict when that will be.

<sup>1 - In theory you can use it "forever" ... but you may run into dependency conflicts if you use / upgrade to some version of another library that depends on a later version of the Apache Commons.</sup>